# How to efficiently cache and apply scipy gammaln to a numpy array?

Tags: python, caching, scipy, gamma-function

I am looking for a way to cache the results of the gammaln function, apply it to a numpy array and then sum the results. Currently I am able to cache the gammln results using a simple dictionary approach, but it seems that I cannot iterate the array efficiently. Below is an illustrative code snipet of the problem.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gammaln

gammaln_cache_dic = {}
def gammaln_cache(x):
    if x not in gammaln_cache_dic:
        val = gammaln(x)
        gammaln_cache_dic[x] = val
    else:
        val = gammaln_cache_dic[x]
    return val

def cache_gammaln_sum(M):
    res_sum = 0.0
    for x in np.fromiter( [ x for x in M ], int ):
        res_sum += gammaln_cache(x)
    return res_sum

np_array = np.random.randint(5, size=(500))*1000+3
start = time.time()
for i in np_array:
    gammaln(i)
end = time.time()
print("NO cache gammaln %f secs" % (end - start))

start = time.time()
for i in np_array:
    gammaln_cache(i)
end = time.time()
print("cache gammaln %f secs" % (end - start))

start = time.time()
gammaln(np_array).sum()
end = time.time()
print("NO cache gammaln sum %f secs" % (end - start))

start = time.time()
cache_gammaln_sum(np_array)
end = time.time()
print("cache gammaln sum %f secs" % (end - start))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function has been written to take advantage of the `numpy` compiled code (or itself is compiled), it will be hard to improve on its performance with caching.

```
In [1]: from scipy.special import gammaln
In [2]: np_array = np.random.randint(5, size=(500))*1000+3
In [3]: np_array.shape
Out[3]: (500,)
In [4]: timeit gammaln(np_array).sum()
....
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.9 µs per loop
```

Evaluating each element will be much slower

```
In [5]: timeit sum([gammaln(i) for i in np_array])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.8 ms per loop
```

Simply iterating through the array is slower.

```
In [6]: timeit sum([i for i in np_array])
10000 loops, best of 3: 127 µs per loop
```

In this case the values are a small set of integers

```
In [10]: np.unique(np_array)
Out[10]: array([   3, 1003, 2003, 3003, 4003])
```

But identifying those unique values takes nearly as long as calculating the function for all 500.

```
In [11]: timeit np.unique(np_array)
...
In [12]: timeit gammaln(np.unique(np_array))
```

In fact it is slower if I also ask for indices that can reconstruct the array:

```
In [14]: timeit np.unique(np_array, return_inverse=True)    
10000 loops, best of 3: 54 µs per loop
```

There are caching or memorizing recipes for Python, including a `@functools.lru_cache` decorator.  But I haven't seen them much with `numpy` arrays.  If your problem is suitable for cacheing I suspect it is best to do that in lower level code, such as with Cython, and using existing C or C++ cache libraries.

### Cache with unique

We could get cache like behavior with `unique` - use it to get both the unique values and the indices that lets us recreate the original array:

```
In [5]: unq, idx=np.unique(np_array, return_inverse=True)
In [6]: res1= gammaln(np_array)
In [7]: res2= gammaln(unq)
In [8]: res2= res2[idx]
In [9]: np.allclose(res1, res2)
Out[9]: True
```

But compare the times:

```
In [10]: timeit res1= gammaln(np_array)
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.1 µs per loop

In [11]: %%timeit
    ...: unq, idx=np.unique(np_array, return_inverse=True)
    ...: res2= gammaln(unq)[idx]
10000 loops, best of 3: 63.3 µs per loop
```

Most of this extra time is in calculating `unique`; once we have the mapping, applying it is quite fast:

```
In [12]: timeit res2=gammaln(unq)[idx]
...
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.12 µs per loop
```

### unique with sum

Returning the sum of values rather than actual values shifts relative times a bit

```
In [13]: %timeit res1= gammaln(np_array).sum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 35.3 µs per loop
In [14]: %%timeit
    ...: unq, idx=np.unique(np_array, return_inverse=True)
    ...: res2= gammaln(unq)[idx].sum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.3 µs per loop
```

With Paul Panzer's count approach

```
In [21]: %%timeit 
    ...: unq, cnt=np.unique(np_array, return_counts=True)
    ...: res=(gammaln(unq)*cnt).sum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 59.5 µs per loop
In [22]: %%timeit 
    ...: unq, cnt=np.unique(np_array, return_counts=True)
    ...: res=np.dot(gammaln(unq),cnt)
10000 loops, best of 3: 52.1 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `np.unique`

```
uniq, counts = np.unique(data, return_counts=True)
result = np.dot(gammaln(uniq), counts)
```

uniq are the sorted unique values in data, the `return_counts` keyword instructs the function to also return the multiplicities.

The second line evaluates `gammaln` once for each distinct element, multiplies with the number of occurrences and sums.

You could also keep `gammaln(uniq)` and use it as a look_up table.

```
look_up = gammaln(uniq)
indices = np.searchsorted(uniq, new_samples)
hit = uniq[indices] == new_samples
result = look_up[indices[hit]]
miss = new_samples[~hit]
```

Comment: @hpaulj I suppose the entire caching thing works best with ints. For continuous functions one would rather setup some grid-based look-up, Essentially what the scipy interp functions do.

Answer (score 2):

`gammaln`, like most functions from `scipy.special` is a ufunc, i.e. given a numpy array, it operates elementwise and returns a numpy array:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from scipy.special import gammaln

In [3]: x = np.arange(1, 8)

In [4]: gammaln(x)
Out[4]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.69314718,  1.79175947,  3.17805383,
        4.78749174,  6.57925121])

In [5]: gammaln(x).sum()
Out[5]: 17.029703434928095
```

In fact, if you give it a list of numbers, it'll convert it to an array internally, so

```
In [6]: gammaln(list(range(1, 8)))
Out[6]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.69314718,  1.79175947,  3.17805383,
        4.78749174,  6.57925121])
```

Also note that ufunc iterations happen in the compiled code. Thus it's unlikely you can do much better performance-wise with any sort of caching and python iterations etc.

Comment: `gammaln` may not be the best example for an expensive function, but the general idea of avoiding redundant evaluations has merit.